# How do I scrape information from a frame using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

This is my first attempt at web scraping. I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to scrape phone numbers from Raymond James' website. An example would be http://www.raymondjames.com/office_locator_display.asp?addressline=90210

Whenever I use BeautifulSoup, I am unable to find the appropriate information in the HTML.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.raymondjames.com/office_locator_display.asp?addressline=90210'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3)        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36')]
page_to_scrape=opener.open(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
```

The output produced does not contain the information I need. It seems the URL I provide does not point to the location frame.

I don't use Python for a whole lot of work with web data so I am ignorant on how to direct Beautiful Soup into the 'frame' in order to get contact information.

Comment: I believe additional javascript code loads the address list after the browser loaded the page. You'll have to analyze the page using your browser developer tools. Look for extra network requests that may contain the addresses, and emulate *those*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Martijn said, dig in the network requests, and the source data is there. In this case it's an xml response to a GET request made in the iframe. Armed with that url, the solution is pretty simple:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://hosted.where2getit.com/raymondjames/ajax?&xml_request=%3Crequest%3E%3Cappkey%3E7BD67064-FC36-11E0-B80D-3AEEDDB2B31E%3C%2Fappkey%3E%3Cformdata+id%3D%22locatorsearch%22%3E%3Cdataview%3Estore_default%3C%2Fdataview%3E%3Climit%3E30%3C%2Flimit%3E%3Cgeolocs%3E%3Cgeoloc%3E%3Caddressline%3E90210%3C%2Faddressline%3E%3Clongitude%3E%3C%2Flongitude%3E%3Clatitude%3E%3C%2Flatitude%3E%3Ccountry%3E%3C%2Fcountry%3E%3C%2Fgeoloc%3E%3C%2Fgeolocs%3E%3Csearchradius%3E25%7C50%7C100%3C%2Fsearchradius%3E%3C%2Fformdata%3E%3C%2Frequest%3E'), 'lxml')
# parse the points of interest into a list
pois = soup.find_all('poi')
# now have your way with them!
```

Comment: Mattexx, thanks for your help. I partially understand the logic and was able to find the url using Chrome's developer tools. Is there a way to use Python to automate the process of uncovering the url? I guess the process would be something along the lines of obtaining the xml responses to the get request and then iterating through the urls to find those that have the the relevant information and then actually scrape the info.

Comment: I don't know a way to use Python to uncover the URL. Since it's loaded in Javascript, a batter tool for this would be a headless browser like Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: Just a little update. Using PhantomJS, I made decent progress by capturing the network requests and responses and displaying them in JSON format. The relevant link is always ID: 60. Now it is just a matter of combining this with BeautifulSoup and then making a little script that iterates through the zip codes I'm interested in. Thanks for your guidance.